# Can't import custom Vue3 library, browser says "Component is missing template or render function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to export my Vue component library, via Vite. I can only import the library and use it if I do it from the Main.js file. However, if I wanted to register the components locally, for example within App.vue, using "import ComponentName from './path'" I get "Component is missing template or render function" as a response from the browser.

## Index.js

```
import VbButton from './components/Comm/VbButton.vue';
  import VbInput from './components/Comm/VbInput.vue';


  const components = {
    VbButton,
    VbInput,
  }

export default{
    install: (app)=>{
        Object.entries(components).forEach(([name, component]) => {
            app.component(name, component);    
        });
    },
}
```

## Package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "vuebotics",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "files":["dist"],
  "main":"./dist/vuebotics.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/vuebotics.es.js",
  "exports":{
    ".":{
      "import":"./dist/vuebotics.es.js",
      "require":"./dist/vuebotics.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css":"./dist/style.css"
  },


  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apexcharts": "^3.44.0",
    "flowbite": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vuese": "^1.4.7"
  }
}
```

## Vite.Config.JS

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build:{
    lib:{
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
      name: "VueBotics",
      fileName: (format) => `vuebotics.${format}.js`
    },
    rollupOptions:{
      external:["vue"],
      output:{
        globals:{
          vue: "Vue",

        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js - Component is missing template or render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64409157/vue-js-component-is-missing-template-or-render-function)

Comment: " However, if I wanted to register the components locally, for example within App.vue," - it's unknown what your code looks like. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem